# iPad 4 Lightning audio while charging?

Tags: ipad, audio, charging, lightning

I bought a used iPad 4 mini to try out some music recording software. I use an external audio interface (iRig Pro Duo) connected to the Lightning port for audio recording, playback and MIDI.

Is there any way to charge/power the iPad while doing this? Is there an adapter that allows a charger to connect while providing full functionality of the Lightning port?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which I will post here for the benefit of others. What is needed is a "Lightning to USB3 Camera Adaptor" which allows USB3 and Lightning devices to be connected simultaneously. So you can use the Apple Charger to power the iPad through the lightning port, and connect other devices via USB3. (Not sure if you can power the iPad via the USB3.)

(Thank you "IconDaemon" for making minor corrections to my punctuation and grammar.)